# The method onCreate1(Bundle) of type MainActivity must override or implement a super type method?

Tags: java, android

```
.    
.
Parameters params; 


        @Override
        protected void onCreate2(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
            setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);
```

Compiler has been verified as 1.6.

Have read all the other questions regarding this issue.

Comment: use `onCreate` instead of `onCreate2` as method name because no such method is available with name of `onCreate2` in Activity

Comment: OnCreate is being used further up in the activity.

Comment: if `onCreate2` is custom method then remove `@Override` from it or if method is available in any custom class then extends  class to override method

Comment: Removing @Overide and some other changes and the app is running!